# why boostrap/start.php is not in gitignore (laravel)

Tags: database, git, laravel-4

I have question why boostrap/start.php is not in git ignore...

Well I do not want to commit db password to the repo so I will write it in .env.local.php and then access it via $_ENV in database.php but I need to define hostname in bootstrap/start.php

But I am working with my friend so he needs to put his hostname there too... but what if my friend wanna work on production enviroment? so he will change it but if he makes commit then it will push to the repo... I do not think that this is nice...

Am I doing it wrong or it is a normal way how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: I personally modified the `detectEnvironment()` call in `bootstrap/start.php` to look for a specific environment variable in PHP (defaulting back to local, not production).  So if you want to set up a staging/production server, the Apache/PHP configuration needs to confirm to the repository..otherwise, you can still work on a local setup.

Answer (score 1):

you shoud try this

http://crynobone.com/posts/5/alternative-environment-detection-for-laravel-4

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function ()
{
    return require __DIR__.'/environment.php';
});
```